# Matlab Find Internal Contours in a binary Image?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

HI 
I am using Matlab .
How can I find internal contours in a binary image. 
Can anybody tell me a simple way or provide me code example.
This is related to my assignment.
Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **bwtraceboundary**, here is the example:

```
BW = imread('blobs.png');  
imshow(BW,[]);  
s=size(BW);  
for row = 2:55:s(1)  
   for col=1:s(2)  
      if BW(row,col),  
         break;  
      end  
   end  

   contour = bwtraceboundary(BW, [row, col], 'W', 8, 50,...
                                   'counterclockwise');  
   if(~isempty(contour))  
      hold on;  
      plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);  
      hold on;  
      plot(col, row,'gx','LineWidth',2);  
   else  
      hold on; plot(col, row,'rx','LineWidth',2);  
   end  
end
```